# Cassandra 2.1 crashes with Native memory allocation failure

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra, jvm, datastax

On a 6 node Cassandra (datastax-community-2.1) cluster running on EC2 (i2.xlarge) instances, Jvm hosting the cassandra service randomly crashes with following error.

```
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 12288 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (os_linux.cpp:2747), pid=26159, tid=140305605682944
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_60-b19) (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.60-b09 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000008341000):  JavaThread "MemtableFlushWriter:2055" daemon [_thread_new, id=23336, stack(0x00007f9b71c56000,0x00007f9b71c97000)]

Stack: [0x00007f9b71c56000,0x00007f9b71c97000],  sp=0x00007f9b71c95820,  free space=254k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x99e7ca]  VMError::report_and_die()+0x2ea
V  [libjvm.so+0x496fbb]  report_vm_out_of_memory(char const*, int, unsigned long, char const*)+0x9b
V  [libjvm.so+0x81d81e]  os::Linux::commit_memory_impl(char*, unsigned long, bool)+0xfe
V  [libjvm.so+0x81d8dc]  os::pd_commit_memory(char*, unsigned long, bool)+0xc
V  [libjvm.so+0x81565a]  os::commit_memory(char*, unsigned long, bool)+0x2a
V  [libjvm.so+0x81bdcd]  os::pd_create_stack_guard_pages(char*, unsigned long)+0x6d
V  [libjvm.so+0x9522de]  JavaThread::create_stack_guard_pages()+0x5e
V  [libjvm.so+0x958c24]  JavaThread::run()+0x34
V  [libjvm.so+0x81f7f8]  java_start(Thread*)+0x108
```

Modifications in cassandra-env.sh

```
MAX_HEAP_SIZE="8G"
HEAP_NEWSIZE="800M"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=50"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+AggressiveOpts"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+UseLargePages"
```

Here are the full jvm crash logs from two machines

- [db_06](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mbfzivvtvg6a4m6/db06_hs_err_pid26159.log.zip?dl=0)
- [db_05](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cob9enxrg4a7mpr/db_05_hs_err_pid25411.log.zip?dl=0)

Writes are about 10K-15K/sec and there are very few reads. Cassandra 2.0.9 with same settings never crashed. Any clues to what might be causing the to crashes?

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like it might be a bug.  Would you mind creating a Jira ticket here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:summary-panel ?

Comment: Created a bug for this issue. (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8152)